# What is the plug is on the Plugable MXChip AZ3166 IoT DevKit?

Tags: hardware, iot-devkit

I'm looking at prototyping a couple of solutions using the MXChip AZ3166 that require a number of external devices like GPS, Display and Comms hardware.

Does anyone know what connectors can be used with the "Pluggable" MXChip AZ3166 IOT Devkit, or if there are any breakout boards available for it?

Answer (score 3):

In Mxchip AZ3166, there is a edge connector on the board that is compatible with BBC Micro:bit accessories. So you could easily extend it with external devices.

More information of Micro:Bit could be find here: https://www.kitronik.co.uk/microbit/bbc-micro-bit-accessories.html

And you could check this example https://github.com/jimbobbennett/InternetConnectedFan on how to use Micro:Bit to connect to external devices.

Comment: AdaFruit also sell a "DragonTail" board for breaking out this header into breadboard-style headers: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3695 (The PCB files are open source, available at https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-DragonTail-for-micro-bit-PCB)